# Why do my environment variables keep getting wiped out in Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh, environment-variables

I am currently using MacOS Catalina, and every time my computer boots up from having shut down the environment variables get wiped out. I literally have to manually run `export FOO=bar` each time my computer boots up.

I have tried adding the environment variables to `~/.bash_profile` but that doesn't seem to work, I think because Catalina uses zsh as opposed to bash. (Is there a way to switch back?)

Anyways, how do I persist environment variables so that I don't have to manually export them every time? Could something be wrong with my computer that's causing this? There are also some other weird issues when my computer does a fresh boot.

Comment: If you create a user account cold under Catalina, that account's shell will be zsh.  If you upgrade a machine to Catalina, existing user accounts will retain whatever their shell was before.  So, don't guess, what *is* the shell you are using?

Comment: @MarcWilson I think mine got upgraded to zsh somehow, it's *definitely* not bash. I upgraded to Catalina and these are very old accounts.

Comment: What does 'echo $SHELL' say your shell is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a file `~/.zshrc` and put your `export` statements in there. The shell does not magically remember what you exported last time. You will need to put them in a file that will get sourced each time you start your shell, such as `.zshrc`.

Comment: Though it’s kind of a tradition to put them in ~/.zshenv

Comment: Unless `/etc/zshenv` disables it or Zsh was started with `zsh -f`, `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshenv` will get sourced for _all_ instances of Zsh, including non-login non-interactive instances. It's usually best to keep that file as small as possible or not even use it at all. Putting everything in `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc` is what most people should be doing.

Comment: yes, i figured it out thanks. i also mentioned bash_profile which i was using before it updated to zsh. thanks tho

Comment: @janedoe Can you accept my answer, then? :)